# Using Over Partition in sql compared with group by

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count, database-partitioning

Given the table creation code bellow, is there an alternative method(s) to display the same result to

```
select b.*, count(*) over (partition by colour) bricks_total 
from bricks b;
```

using `group by` and `count(*)`? And what's the difference in this case?

```
create table bricks 
(
     brick_id integer,
     colour   varchar2(10),
     shape    varchar2(10),
     weight   integer
);

insert into bricks values (1, 'blue', 'cube', 1);
insert into bricks values (2, 'blue', 'pyramid', 2);
insert into bricks values (3, 'red', 'cube', 1);
insert into bricks values (4, 'red', 'cube', 2);
insert into bricks values (5, 'red', 'pyramid', 3);
insert into bricks values (6, 'green', 'pyramid', 1);

commit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query puts the total for each colour on each row:

```
select b.*, count(*) over (partition by colour) as bricks_total
from bricks b;
```

Before window functions, a typical solution would be a correlated subquery:

```
select b.*,
       (select count(*) from bricks b2 where b2.colour = b.colour) as bricks_total
from bricks b;
```

You can also express this using `join` and aggregation:

```
select b.*, bb.bricks_total
from bricks b join
     (select bb.colour, count(*) as bricks_total
      from bricks bb
      group by bb.colour
     ) bb
     using (colour);
```

These are not 100% the same.  The difference is that the original code will return the count of `colour` even when the value is `NULL`.  This code returns `0`.

So, a more precise equivalent would be:

```
select b.*,
       (select count(*)
        from bricks b2
        where b2.colour = b.colour or
              b2.colour is null and b.colour is null
       ) as bricks_total
from bricks b;
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot for the effort, but what does the b2 stands for?

Comment: @AbbasFadhil . . . It is a *table alias*(.

Comment: I mean't I couldn't understand why you used it in [b2.colour = b.colour] when both of them are referring to the same value, isn't there a way around without using other aliases? it's like saying [if 1=1 -> return value]

Comment: @AbbasFadhil . . . That is how a *correlated subquery* works.